# Wikipedia (JWBF API) под приложение Android

Tags: java, android, mediawiki-api

Пишу приложение Android под Wikipedia с использованием википедиевского JWBF API, и после написания в методе `onCreate()` вот этих строк

```
import net.sourceforge.jwbf.core.actions.util.ActionException;
import net.sourceforge.jwbf.core.actions.util.ProcessException;
import net.sourceforge.jwbf.core.contentRep.SimpleArticle;
import net.sourceforge.jwbf.mediawiki.bots.MediaWikiBot;
.................................
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    try {

        MediaWikiBot b = new MediaWikiBot("http://en.wikipedia.org/w/");
        b.login("UserName", "***");
        SimpleArticle sa = new SimpleArticle(b.readContent("Main Page"));
        System.out.println(sa.getText());
    } 
    catch(ActionException e)
    {

    }
    catch(ProcessException e)
    {

    }
}
```

---

LogCat: Could not find class 'net.sourceforge.jwbf.mediawiki.bots.MediaWikiBot', referenced from method com.example.wikiandroid.MainActivity.onCreate

Jar файлы я все что были в этом API при билд_пассел в проект пробывал писать в AndroidManifes:

```
<uses-library android:name="net.sourceforge.jwbf.mediawiki.bots"/>
```

тогда при дэбаге на устройство, в `LogCat` пишет:

```
[2012-10-29 00:00:22 - WikiAndroid] 
Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY
[2012-10-29 00:00:22 - WikiAndroid] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2012-10-29 00:00:23 - WikiAndroid] Launch canceled!
```

потом сыпятся жёлтые надписи там же

```
VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 28 (Lnet/sourceforge/jwbf/mediawiki/bots/MediaWikiBot;) in Lcom/example/wikiandroid/MainActivity;
VFY: unable to find exception handler at addr 0x2b
VFY:  rejected Lcom/example/wikiandroid/MainActivity;.onCreate (Landroid/os/Bundle;)V
Verifier rejected class Lcom/example/wikiandroid/MainActivity;
Class init failed in newInstance call (Lcom/example/wikiandroid/MainActivity;)
```

Целый день думаю как это починить в Google искал, но нигде нормально не объясняют как отладить..
За толковую подсказку буду благодарен!

Comment: а ты их к проекту подключил в иде?

Comment: Да подключал: импортировал в libs, потом в билд пасе подключал jars...
И всё равно такое выдаёт
Вот сайт API Wikipedia если кто захочет попробовать http://jwbf.sourceforge.net/pw/index.php?n=Site.Features

Comment: Может я далеко полез и в Android есть что-то встроенное уже для работы с Wiki??

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте зайти в

```
java build path - order and export - и поставить птичку на android privat lib
```

Answer (score 0):

Тоже самое с библиотекой iText. Все работало нормально потом обновил Eclipse SDK итд теперь выдает такие сообщения.

> : Could not find class
> 'com.itextpdf.text.Document',
> referenced from method
> ru.freqnsy.recosys.pdf.PdfCreater.PCreate
>
> : VFY: unable to resolve new-instance
> 62 (Lcom/itextpdf/text/Document;) in
> Lru/freqnsy/recosys/pdf/PdfCreater;
>
> : VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0000
>
> : VFY: unable to resolve exception
> class 63
> (Lcom/itextpdf/text/DocumentException;)
>
> : VFY: unable to find exception
> handler at addr 0x943
>
> : VFY:  rejected
> Lru/freqnsy/recosys/pdf/PdfCreater;.PCreate
> ()V
>
> : VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x0d at
> 0x0943
>
> : Verifier rejected class
> Lru/freqnsy/recosys/pdf/PdfCreater;
>
> : Shutting down VM
>
> : threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d5a0)

Спасибо Gorets, приложение стало выполнять свои функции.
Но в логе проскакивает несколько ошибок подобного типа:

> W: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/awt/print/PrinterJob;) 
> W: Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/itextpdf/awt/PdfGraphics2D;
>
> W: Link of class 'Lcom/itextpdf/awt/PdfGraphics2D;' failed
>
> W: Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/itextpdf/awt/PdfPrinterGraphics2D; (72)
>
> W: Link of class 'Lcom/itextpdf/awt/PdfPrinterGraphics2D;' failed
>
> E: Could not find class 'com.itextpdf.awt.PdfPrinterGraphics2D', referenced from method com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte.createPrinterGraphics
>
> W: VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 73 (Lcom/itextpdf/awt/PdfPrinterGraphics2D;) in Lcom/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfContentByte;

Что это может значить, и на сколько это важно?